# window.jQuery==true evaluates to false, although window.jQuery!=false evaluates to true

Tags: javascript

This is something I cannot get my head round.

It was my understanding that JavaScript had **truthy** and **falsy** values:

#### Falsy values:

0
false
undefined
null
NaN
"" (empty string)

#### Truthy values:

Anything that isn't a falsy value

If window.jQuery has loaded correctly, then it shouldn't evaluate to false (or rather, `undefined`). The following condition will return **`true`**:

```
window.jQuery != false
```

However, the following condition will return **`false`**:

```
window.jQuery == true
```

(I'm using `==` for all of these, rather than `===`, otherwise window.jQuery will always evaluate to `false` unless it is literally a boolean containing the value `false`).

What is happening here? Surely if a condition doesn't evaluate to `false`, then it must evaluate to `true`?

Comment: Because you're ultimately comparing a string to a number. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: JavaScript does have truthies and falsies, but what you are expecting here is two different truthies (`jQuery` and `true`) to compare equal to each other. That's another thing entirely.

Comment: `5` is truthy, and `10` is truthy, but you wouldn't expect `5 == 10` to be true, would you?

Comment: !(window.jQuery == true)  is not the same thing as window.jQuery != false. These are two different expressions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`jQuery` is a function, and it's not `== true`, so you get `false`, and it's `!= false` so you get `true`.

I think you've got the idea that a `==` comparison is the same as a boolean conversion. It's not. To do a boolean conversion, you could do `Boolean(window.jQuery) == true`, and you'll get `true`. Or just `!!window.jQuery == true`.

When you convert to a boolean value, *then* you get conversion to `true` in all cases except `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""` and `0`.

Ultimately if you want to see if jQuery is loaded, then you'd just do...

```
if (window.jQuery) {
```

Which will perform the boolean conversion for you.

Comment: I still don't understand - how can something not evaluate to either false **or** true?

Comment: Well, any value that isn't `true` and isn't `false`, will go through a process of type coercion in order to perform the comparison. The process of type coercion used by `==` isn't a simple boolean conversion. It's much more complex.

Comment: There are lots of values that don't evaluate to false or true. `3`, `null`, `"foo"`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `{key: 3}`.

Comment: I think I understand now - my mistake was that `==` would convert everything to a boolean before comparing, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

When comparing values of different types, some internal conversions happen implicitly. Assuming jQuery is being used, you would have the following:

For window.jQuery != false:

1. window.jQuery != false
2. window.jQuery.toString() != 0
3. "function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}" != 0
4. Number("function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}") != 0
5. NaN != 0
6. true

For window.jQuery == true, something similar happens:

1. window.jQuery == true
2. window.jQuery.toString() == 1
3. "function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}" == 1
4. Number("function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}") == 1
5. NaN == 1
6. false

Source: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

When you compare values with `true` or `false`, it doesn't just compare their truthiness. `true` and `false` are specific values, just like different numbers and strings. Just because two values have the same truthiness, doesn't mean they actually compare equal.

If you want to compare the truthiness of two values, you can do it by forcing them to boolean types. A simple way to do this is with boolean inversion:

```
if (!foo == !bar)
```

will tell if `foo` and `bar` have the same truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see if jQuery is loaded or not.  This will tell you.

```
if (jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Check out this blog post:

[Check if jQuery is Loaded](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html)

Comment: In fact, this will throw an error: if jQuery isn't defined this error is raised (in Chrome, at least) `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `. One would need `window.jQuery`.